# How can I pass the PHP variable to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I am new to PHP. I want to pass the php variable into my javascript file. But it was not converted. I already defined the value of $val in php file. I write following code in my `index.js` file;

```
var val = "<?php echo $val ?>";
console.log(val);
```

but my console shows output as : `<?php echo $val ?>`. It is not taking the php variable value. Any help?

Comment: PHP does not run on `.js` files.

Comment: I follow https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/scalar.php#targetText=To%20pass%20scalar%20data%20held,for%20use%20in%20your%20scripts. this tutorial.

Comment: @Tekson Where does that tutorial say that you can put the PHP code in a `.js` file? It says you're supposed to put it in the JavaScript segment of a PHP script.

Comment: Ok I got that thank you. I insert It into js file. But actually I have to insert above expression in php file using `<script>` tag. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include script at bottom of your page PHP FILE

```
  <script>
   var val = "<?php echo $val ?>";
   console.log(val);
  </script>
```

Comment: Actually, I write the code on the js file directly. I connect both php file and js file in same html file.

Comment: As above suggestion, I put my code into php file using `<script>` tag. This solve my issue. My mistake was I doen't put my code into js file. js can't run php file. Thank you!